# Unable to upload file while recording in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to record some user actions performed on UI, using JMeter. As I try to upload a file, I choose file and click upload. But the upload doesn't take place. This problem appears only during the recording and not when I perform the same action without JMeter.
Could you please suggest what could be possible reasons and possible solutions?
I am using firefox and JMeter 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

**You need to copy the file(s) you're uploading to the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**, only this way JMeter will be able to properly build the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)